# Google calendar reminder via API not working

Tags: c#, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am trying to [Insert](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) a new event to Google Calendar with 2 custom reminders, but they are not being set.

It seems like reminders 7+9 minutes are set via code (check output).

But in the calendar Web GUI, the event shows up with the default reminders set.

```
            // Insert new
        var r1 = new EventReminder { Method = "popup", Minutes = 7 };
        var r2 = new EventReminder { Method = "popup", Minutes = 9 };
        var erd = new Event.RemindersData {UseDefault = false, Overrides = new [] {r1 , r2}};

        var ev = new Event
        {
            Created = DateTime.Now,
            Creator = new Event.CreatorData {DisplayName = "Foobar"},
            Description = "Foo",
            Summary = "Bar",
            Location = "Baz",
            Reminders = erd,
            Start = new EventDateTime {DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1)},
            End = new EventDateTime {DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(2)}
        };

        try
        {
            var eventInsert = service.Events.Insert(ev, "***************'");
            var execResult = eventInsert.Execute();
            Console.WriteLine(execResult.Status);
            Console.WriteLine(execResult.Id);

            foreach (var r in execResult.Reminders.Overrides)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" mins: " + r.Minutes);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.Message);
        }
```

Output:

```
confirmed
7ktkgedd536f********
mins: 7
mins: 9
```

Result image URL:

[image: result]

Comment: I think that there is a ceiling from 7 to 10 minutes. Did you try out some round numbers, as 10 or 20?

Comment: @VMAtm Yeah tried others as well, 30,40,90 nothing works. Also the way to verify that my default values are used, is by seeing that combo (email+popup). In code I set 2x popup, but still 10 popup + 10 email is used => defaults.

Comment: This sounds like a bug but the question is it a bug in the API or the client library.   Will have to test this when I get home.

Comment: I got it to work using the try me. https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert  your code looks right.   SO its making me think even more its a client lib issue.

Comment: It's worth to check how the HTTP request looks like in both cases, to see if the .NET client library is missing a field. Can you attach those ones to the description?

Comment: @peleyal I have no idea how to do that, I tried fiddler but since it's HTTPS, with fiddler in the middle, the google library throws an invalid certificate exception. How do I capture/show http(s) traffic from inside my C# console application?

Comment: http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/DecryptHTTPS

Comment: @peleyal Problem is that by using that method Fiddler sits in between, and the google module in C# does certificate validation, so it fails with an exception (Probably fiddler provides it's own certficate in order to be able to sit in the middle and decrypt the traffic) http://i.imgur.com/arxJ6cl.png

Comment: I tried it before and it worked for me. You just have Fiddler as a man in the middle :) But that's OK to get the right HTTP request+response. Do you use service account or a regular OAuth 2.0 flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got the time to further investigate this.
@peleyal got me on the right track, I was using a **service account**.

**Switching to OAuth solved the problem.**

Comment: So if we are using a service account it wouldn't work?